# PHP: Stream PDF (make PDF accessible only from webpage)

Tags: php, pdf, streaming

I have a site built in PHP and we have some PHP pages that require logging in that produce links to PDFs. The problem is that those PDFs (which were copied out to Amazon Cloudfront) were indexed and available for searching.

What is the easiest way to stream an existing PDF to the browser, making it so that the user has to login to be able to see the document? I'm hoping that there is some simple Header code or something where I can say "load this file on the server that's not accessible on the web and output it as PDF".

Any thoughts/suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use htaccess (or similar) to redirect any requests for a .pdf document to a PHP script, passing the requested file name. The script can then validate the log-in credentials, and if the user is logged in it can then send PDF headers, fetch the PDF document (`file_get_contents`) and output the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can either block access to files (as mentioned in the other answer) or (more cleverly, IMHO) you can pass the file through to the browser after checking credentials (or doing pretty much anything) in PHP.  There are code examples and a discussion here: http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/159354-pass-through-any-file